# c# Sqlite query single string instance

Tags: c#, sql, database, string, sqlite

i have sqlite DB that saves Factory names with Id. I want to get name using the id.

```
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadCOnnectionSring()))
            {
                var name = cnn.Query("select Name from Factory where Id = "+ factoryId).ToString();
                return name;
            }
```

It's returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the factoryId is valid and secured against SQL-injection,
maybe this could work:

```
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadCOnnectionSring()))
            {
                var name = cnn.Query<string >("select Name from Factory where Id = "+ factoryId).First();
                return name;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "sqlite_connection_string";
        string sqlQuery = "select Name from Factory where Id = "+ factoryId;

        using var connection= new SQLiteConnection(connectionString );
        connection.Open();

        using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
        string name = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```